# Hibernate / HSQLDB in memory: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: hibernate, exception, hsqldb

I am building simple crud app with hibernate / in memory hsqldb, without spring.

I thought this might be version incompatibility, but upgrading did not help. I tried to change hbm2ddl.auto to "update" but it did not help as well.

Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ACCOUNT
```

Sql:

```
insert into Account (id, balance, creationDate, currency, isActive, lastModificationDate, username) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Message:

```
could not prepare statement
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;

    @Column(length = 16)
    private String username;
    @Column(precision = 2)
    private BigDecimal balance;
    private Currency currency;
    private boolean isActive;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationDate;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModificationDate;
}
```

Method:

```
@Override
public String save(Account account) {
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSesssionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    String id = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        id = String.valueOf(session.save(account));
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException e){
        transaction.rollback();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return id;
}
```

Config:

```
public static SessionFactory getSesssionFactory(){
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
            .addAnnotatedClass(Transfer.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Account.class)
            .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "sa")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "")
            .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Every time your method is called, you create a new session facory, which recreates he database schema. That's really, really not a good idea.

Comment: @JBNizet yes... good point, thank you. I am junior developer and I tried not to use spring for practice at home and I am terrified about lacks of my knowledge when I cant rely on spring

Comment: So the answer to the problem is that Id can not be string, it has to be Long value type.